# How can i make packages in a maven project?

Tags: maven, module, package

I'm beginner with maven, and i have to do a packages on multi-module project.

I don't really understand how to do this and the goal of doing it.

[How my project look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tExWp.png)

And the instruction is just "Building the packages".

Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a confusion in your question. You need to make submodules, not packages.

On the screenshot:

- `multimod` is a parent module.
- `dao` and `web` are sub-modules.

pom.xml in the parent module will contain list of submodules:

```xml
<modules>
    <module>dao</module>
    <module>web</module>
    <!-- other submodules -->         
</modules>
```

Probably you will also need `ear` submodule to package `dao` and `web`.

Check this article: https://www.baeldung.com/maven-multi-module

Each of you modules should have different packaging type:

- `multimod` - `pom`
- `dao` - `jar`
- `web` - `war`
- `ejb` - `ear`

Each maven module can contain java code in `src/main/java`. There you can place the packages. E.g. directory `src/main/java/a/b/c` is the package `a.b.c`